# Compare Two large csv files

Tags: python, csv, sorting, compare, bigdata

I am trying to compare two large CSV files( 260Gb and 16gb) , I have two approaches in mind,

1. taking out particular columns(using column numbers), append to new csv. I think it might reduce size and then I will be to create chunks
2. each time run a code to extract a set of columns based on a one column value, eg:
   if col['name'] == 'disney' , then take out rows matching that value and append to new csv.
   Finally comparing new csv with 16gb csv file.

Any suggestions on what would be the best approach here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you might be able to provide some more details here: could you provide the dataset specs, your code (if any, currently), and specific analyses you're looking to do? Off the top of my head, just given the massive size of your .csv files, you'll probably want to use the Dask package in Python. If you use something like pandas, you're probably going to run out of memory.

Comment: I tried reading whole data at once with Dask, but didn't try comparing it with Dask, can try that.

Comment: Details: so I have a 260gb ( main file ) which has more than 200 million rows and 53 columns , I wish to compare the data in this 260gb CSV with a number of 16/8gb csvs, these are the original files using which 260gb file was created. I am trying to look for discrepancies that were created at the time of generating the resultant file ( 260gb one)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a small worked example, e.g. show say 5 rows from both CSV files (in text format) and show your expected output

Comment: Why do you need to use CSVs? Upload the data to a MariaDB/Postgres table, then do whatever you need to there.